# Return datatbase stream file to WebPage from ASHX

Tags: c#, asp.net

I successfully could save a binary stream field to database (pdf, jpg, etc) and return it to my Webpage like this in a ASP.net Gridview:

```
  <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="ID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Formularios/file.ashx?ID={0}" HeaderText="Documento" 
            DataTextFormatString="{0}" Target="_top" Text="Download document" />
```

and in file.ashx

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    using (OficiosRecibidosDataContext db = new OficiosRecibidosDataContext())
    {
        int value = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["ID"]);

        OficiosRecibidosDocumentos padDoc = db.OficiosRecibidosDocumentos.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == value);

        if (padDoc == null) return;

        string strMIME = "";

        switch (padDoc.Extension.Trim())
        {
            case ".jpg":
                strMIME = "image/jpeg";
                break;
            case ".xls":
                strMIME = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                break;
            case ".xlsx":
                strMIME = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                break;
            case ".doc":
                strMIME = "application/msword";
                break;
            case ".docx":
                strMIME = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
                break;
            case ".pdf":
                strMIME = "application/pdf";
                break;
            default:
                strMIME = "application/octet-stream";
                break;
        }            

        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachement filename=" + padDoc.NombreArchivo.Trim() + padDoc.Extension.Trim());
        context.Response.ContentType = strMIME;
        context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])padDoc.Contenido.ToArray());
        context.Response.End();            
    }        
}

public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is my record

[image]

Everything works fine but when im using Firefox and click ond Download Document an "open /save as" dialog pop up appears and if I select "save/as" the file that is downloaded is called "file.ashx". where I am wrong?  Is not  context.Response.AddHeader suppose to be where I indicate the name and extension of the output file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + padDoc.NombreArchivo.Trim() + padDoc.Extension.Trim() + "\"");
```

First of all, you spelled `attachment` wrong.

Second, it needs a `;` between it and the filename.

And not related to your error, but if your filename has a space in it, it would give a truncated filename.

Comment: You're welcome. Sometimes you stare at a piece of code for so long that you don't see anything anymore. A fresh pair of eyes can be helpful.